# How to edit the properties of DropDownChoiceField lookup field list on the edit form?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two types of lookup list field. How to dynamically change the value of the second field when user change first field? Here is my binding code (web-part code to edit item form):

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        SPFormContext fc = SPContext.Current.FormContext;

        foreach (BaseFieldControl bfc in fc.FieldControlCollection)
        {
            if (bfc.FieldName == "type12")
            {
                DropDownList ddl = FindControlRecursive(bfc, "Lookup") as DropDownList;
                if (ddl != null)
                    ddl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:alert('Test')");
            }
        }
    }


    public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
    {
        if (root.ID == id)
            return root;

        foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
        {
            Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
            if (t != null)
                return t;
        }

        return null;
    }
```